# bash script output [display in table format in my html code in same script]

Tags: html, bash

when I am running the bash script the output is not displayed in tabular format.

I tried various method like storing all information in 1 variable in table format and calling that variable in my html code but it didn't work. i am generating html file in the bash script and trying to catch the value of variable declared above in the bash script. but the problem i am facing is that i a am able to view output in table format in console, however i am not able to view the output in tabular format in my html code. I even tried saving the the output of bash script into 1 variable and that variable saves the information in table format and calling that variable in my html code, but it didnt work that way either. Below is my bash script code and my html code

```
#!bin/bash
 pids=$(ps -eo pid,%cpu,cmd --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR <= 6 {print $1}')
times=$(ps -eo pid,%cpu,cmd --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR <= 6 {print $2}')
processes=$(ps -eo pid,%cpu,cmd --sort=-%cpu | awk 'NR <= 6 {print $3}')

# Displaying the extracted information
echo -e "\n***************Top 6 CPU-Consuming Processes************"
echo -e "PID\tTime\tProcess"
paste <(echo -e "$pids") <(echo -e "$times") <(echo -e "$processes") | column -t

# Save information to a log file (including headers)
echo -e "\n**********Top CPU-Consuming Processes**********" >> Automation.log
echo -e "PID\tTime\tProcess" >> Automation.log
paste <(echo -e "$pids") <(echo -e "$times") <(echo -e "$processes") | column -t >> Automation.log

cat <<EOF > "$html_file"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <special-header>
    </special-header>
   
    <main>
        <section id="image">
            <img src="images/linux.png" alt="Linux Image" class="medium-image center-image">
        </section>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#option1">User Logged info</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#option2">Current Process</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#option3">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#option4">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="option1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Users Logged in system</h3>
                <br>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">Total User</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">$username_logged</th>
                            <td>$date_logged</td>
                            <td>$time_logged</td>
                            <td>$total_user_logged</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="option2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Current Process</h3>
                <br>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">PIDS</th>
                            <th scope="col">Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">Process</th>
                            <th scope="col">Total User</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">$pids</th>
                            <td>$times</td>
                            <td>$process</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>
    </main>
    <special-footer></special-footer>
    <script src="./header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
# **
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Did  you look inside of your `$html_file` ? (by the way, that variable is undefined in your sample code). Also read about [mcve]. Good luck.

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.